# How and in what ways has our understanding of the historical method improved since the publication of E. H. Carr's "What is History" in 1961?

Tags: historiography

This is partially answered in [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/what-is-the-nature-of-questions-that-can-be-answered-by-historical-sources-and-m), but that only characterizes the modern consensus on what history is able to answer - it does not go into depth about how that modern consensus has evolved.

Since Carr's seminal publication was so instrumental in kickstarting that dialogue, I thought I would ask for an account of this evolution after 1961.

Comment: This **[1997 review](https://reviews.history.ac.uk/review/41a)** by A  Munslow might interest you.

Comment: What were Carr's specific contributions to historiography?